# Slightly rotate ActionBar in Android: Possible or not?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

It's been a while since I've posted my last android related question, but here we go.

I'd like to rotate the action bar by 2 or 3 degrees, direction is irrelevant. Is there any way this is possible to do? Since there is seemingly no way to directly access the action bar's view, I'm currently running out of ideas here.

I've also tried to just set the rotated background as a background asset, which is okay, but not the perfect solution.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: While that feels like an awkward thing to do, I'll bet you could fork ActionBarSherlock, and tweak their code.

Comment: Matt, that's indeed awkward. I just want to be sure that I've evaluated all possibilities before going done that path.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Because it looks nice. Seriously, customer's designer. Just trying to do my job here ;)

Comment: As far as I know, your best options will be to rotate everything manually as assets (Background, icon, etc) or to fork ActionBarSherlock. If you figure something else out, be sure to post it here though!